# "Error in parse(text = x)" when running for-loop with ggplot2

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm trying to run a for-loop that produces plots with column names as the x label. This should be straightforward, but R's having an issue parsing the column names since they have parentheses and spaces in them, which I'd like to keep for the plot as they are descriptive author names.

Here are the names of the columns.

```
colnames(shorty_ks)[colnames(shorty_ks)=="K.mean.hr"] <- "BASEmetab"
colnames(shorty_ks)[colnames(shorty_ks)=="kn2o.Churchill"] <- "Churchill et al. (1962)"
colnames(shorty_ks)[colnames(shorty_ks)=="kn2o.Owens"] <- "Owens (1964)"
colnames(shorty_ks)[colnames(shorty_ks)=="kn2o.Oconnor"] <- "OConnor and Dobbins (1958)"
```

Here's the for loop (that works when I use simple text excluding spaces and parentheses):

```
colNames <- names(shorty_ks)[2:4]
BASEmetab <- shorty_ks$BASEmetab


for(i in colNames){
  plt <- ggplot(shorty_ks, aes_string(x=i, y = BASEmetab)) + xlab(bquote(. (i)~k~(h^-1)))+ ylab(expression(BASEmetab~k~(h^-1)))+
theme_gray()+
geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE) + geom_point() +
scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
print(plt)
Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

But when I run the code with the parentheses and spaces, I get this error message:

```
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:11: unexpected symbol
1: Churchill et
              ^
```

Reproducible data:

```
dput(head(shorty_ks))
structure(list(BASEmetab = c(0.11409531425, 0.0716102175833333, 
0.09953587425, 0.248902252416667, 0.114263822125, 0.1530849725
), `Churchill et al. (1962)` = c(0.0354781748244595, 0.0511254328535874, 
0.0351401193406382, 0.0432339955562482, 0.0498228392372491, 
0.0342448057447306
), `OConnor and Dobbins (1958)` = c(0.0336761898724322, 0.0447691111499001, 
0.0333255117582665, 0.0359191513743014, 0.043530785730249, 0.0324037193153706
), `Owens (1964)` = c(0.0585830015888074, 0.10004459351892, 
0.0583011578948275, 
0.102948639254916, 0.0987018589393615, 0.0575186770232462)), .Names = 
c("BASEmetab", 
"Churchill et al. (1962)", "OConnor and Dobbins (1958)", "Owens (1964)"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have space in column names. Column names need to be valid variable names for all the column aesthetic mappings to work. It's better not to change the column names, just have a separate vector of labels you want to use.

Here's the data with the original names

```
shorty_ks <- structure(list(BASEmetab = c(0.11409531425, 0.0716102175833333, 
0.09953587425, 0.248902252416667, 0.114263822125, 0.1530849725
), kn2o.Churchill = c(0.0354781748244595, 0.0511254328535874, 
0.0351401193406382, 0.0432339955562482, 0.0498228392372491, 0.0342448057447306
), kn2o.Oconnor = c(0.0336761898724322, 0.0447691111499001, 0.0333255117582665, 
0.0359191513743014, 0.043530785730249, 0.0324037193153706), kn2o.Owens = c(0.0585830015888074, 
0.10004459351892, 0.0583011578948275, 0.102948639254916, 0.0987018589393615, 
0.0575186770232462)), .Names = c("BASEmetab", "kn2o.Churchill", 
"kn2o.Oconnor", "kn2o.Owens"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then just create a vector of "pretty" names

```
col_labels <- c(
  kn2o.Churchill="Churchill et al. (1962)", 
  kn2o.Oconnor="OConnor and Dobbins (1958)", 
  kn2o.Owens="Owens (1964)")
```

Then you can use that for the labels in the loop

```
colNames <- names(shorty_ks)[2:4]
for(i in colNames){
  plt <- ggplot(shorty_ks, aes_string(x=i, y = "BASEmetab")) + 
    xlab(bquote(. (col_labels[i])~k~(h^-1)))+ 
    ylab(expression(BASEmetab~k~(h^-1)))+
    theme_gray()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE) + geom_point() +
    scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
  print(plt)
}
```

Comment: Fantastic.This worked. Only thing I had to change was `y = "BASEmetab"` to `y = BASEmetab` (didn't need the quotes). Thanks!

Comment: But you've put it in the `aes_string()` which expects character values, not a literal vector or symbol.

Comment: Well it worked when I removed the quotes and didn't when I left the quotes. I got this message when I ran it with quotes `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (42): x, y`

Comment: Oh, is that column still called "K.mean.hr" or is it "BASEmetab" in your shorty_ks table? It needs to match whatever the column name is.

Comment: In the table it's still named "K.mean.hr"

Comment: Then use `aes_string(x=i, y = "K.mean.hr")`

Comment: Worked! Just because I'm curious, do you know a way to convert this from a for-loop to a more robust function?