# Error in parse(text = elt) when using the tab_spanner in a gt table R

Tags: r, gt

I would like to create a `gt` table in R. However, I am facing some issues with the tab spanner  When I try to use:

```
 tab_spanner(
      label = 'If you help me you will be my hero', 
      columns =  names(table2a)[3:8]
   )
```

I really do not understand why since this should be a quite easy thing to do. I have added other elements such as footnotes, source notes and other elements quite smoothly but I am stuck with the tab spanner.
Here is the code:

```
load(paste0(wd ,"/Tables/Table2a.Rdata"))
gt(table2a) %>% 
   tab_spanner(
      label = 'If you help me you will be my hero', 
      columns =  names(table2a)[3:8]
   )
```

and  here is the data if you want to try yourself:

```
> dput(table2a)
structure(list(Indicator = c("Real GDP growth", NA, "Private consumption", 
NA, "Business investment", NA, "Housing investment", NA, "Net exports - contribution to GDP growth", 
NA, "Employment growth", NA, "Compensation per employee", NA), 
    Type = c("Latest Obs.", "(B)MPE", "Latest Obs.", "(B)MPE", 
    "Latest Obs.", "(B)MPE", "Latest Obs.", "(B)MPE", "Latest Obs.", 
    "(B)MPE", "Latest Obs.", "(B)MPE", "Latest Obs.", "(B)MPE"
    ), `2022 Q3` = c(0.8, 0.68, 1.02, 0.83, 2.14, 1.63, -0.77, 
    -0.29, -395.89, -0.08, 0.35, 0.25, 0.77, 0.38), `2022 Q4` = c(0.32, 
    0.13, 0.87, 0.31, 7.73, -0.16, -0.69, -0.27, 99.5, 0.12, 
    0.29, 0.11, 1.09, 1.09), `2023 Q1` = c(NA, -0.06, NA, -0.11, 
    NA, -0.38, NA, -0.15, NA, 0.05, NA, 0.01, NA, 1.26), `2023 Q2` = c(NA, 
    0.02, NA, -0.09, NA, 0.04, NA, -0.3, NA, 0.12, NA, 0.03, 
    NA, 1.46), `2023 Q3` = c(NA, 0.43, NA, 0.36, NA, 0.89, NA, 
    -0.21, NA, 0.18, NA, 0.01, NA, 1.23), `Annual rate of change` = c(NA, 
    3.14, NA, 3.59, NA, 3.35, NA, 2.79, NA, 0.04, NA, 1.98, NA, 
    3.97), CF = c(NA, 3.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), SPF = c(NA, 3.01, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error in parse(text = elt) : <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol
1: Using an
          ^
```

As the error suggests the problem should be related to the names of the columns.
I have read similar issues at the following links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639325/unexpected-symbol-error-in-parsetext-str-with-hyphen-after-a-digit) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334112/error-in-parsetext-x-when-running-for-loop-with-ggplot2) but I am still lost.

Below a screenshot of it
[image]

Comment: This sample data does not elicit the error. Please update your data to include the row that includes the literal text `"Using an"`, it seems like that that row has something different.

Comment: Okay. For comparison, I'm running R-4.2.2, gt-0.8.0 on windows 11. (I'm surprised, because the error message clearly shows the text `Using an`. I've looked in the `gt` repo and can find that literal only in a testthat script, in a comment no less.)

Comment: `R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)`   & `> packageVersion("gt") [1] ‘0.6.0’ ` windows 10

Comment: For me the error is very strange. The code above is just a small portion of a combination of more complex tables. I get the error only when I add the `tab_spanner`. No column has text `Using an`, nor any cell of the table. Honestly, I have no clue of what could be the error.

Comment: I can't find the string in any previous version of `gt` (tested with `git log -p | grep 'Using an'`), and I can't see an error like that being based on the version of R itself. (Assuming that `table2a` truly is verbatim the same...) I can find the string in error messages in the `rmarkdown` package, namely `"Using anchor_sections requires Pandoc 2.0+"`. Verify your version with `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` (returns `'2.17.1.1'` for me).

Comment: Unless you're tied to your current set of packages/versions, perhaps try to update both the `rmarkdown` (2.18) and `gt` packages (0.8.0).

Comment: `> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.6’`

Comment: I have updated both `gt` and `rmarkdown`. `> packageVersion("gt")
[1] ‘0.8.0’` and `> packageVersion("rmarkdown")
[1] ‘2.19’` But I still get the same error. ` rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` returns 2.6

Comment: Have you restarted into a completely-fresh R session? (Make sure you don't have a `.Rdata` file in the project/current directory that would trigger inadvertent data-load and/or package-attachment.) Try a fresh instance to make sure it isn't something hanging around from previous code.

Comment: Lacking insight from that ... now that we've ruled out `gt`, `rmarkdown`, and `pandoc` _versions_ as the immediate culprits, the remaining possibilities are: (1) a bug in one of the packages that is triggered by another package you have loaded or the version or R; or (2) the data in your `Table2a.Rdata` has something not demonstrated in your sample data here.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error too using the pivot_longer function from the tidyR package and it took me quite a while of digging before I discovered that it was an error related to the tidyselect package trying to display the following message:

```
Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
Use `all_of(col_to_select)` instead of `col_to_select` to silence this message.
See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
This message is displayed once per session.
```

(see https://tinyheero.github.io/2020/05/08/use-all-of-tidyverse.html for reference)

Instead, R got stuck and displayed:

```
 Error in parse(text = elt) : <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol
1: Using an
^
```

I had recently updated my rmarkdown package and thought it might be the culprit, especially since for some reason the show traceback feature wasn't working. I then decided to downgrade my rmarkdown version and finally got the traceback to work and discovered the following message:

```
27.parse(text = elt)
26.as.list(parse(text = elt))
25.FUN(X[[i]], ...)
24.lapply(.x, .f, ...)
23.map(x, function(elt) as.list(parse(text = elt)))
22.chr_parse_exprs(x)
21.parse_exprs(x)
20.parse_expr(what)
19.spec_what(spec, "spec", signaller)
18.spec(what, env = env)
17.signal_stage("deprecated", what)
16.lifecycle::deprecate_soft("1.1.0", I("Using an external vector in selections"), 
I("`all_of()` or `any_of()`"), details = c(` ` = "# Was:", 
` ` = glue("data %>% select({name})"), "", ` ` = "# Now:", 
` ` = glue("data %>% select(all_of({name}))"), "", "See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>."), ...
```

I was able to resolve the issue by adding all_of() to my code for selecting columns as suggested in the tidyselect documentation.

Thus, since the gt package also relies on tidyselect, it's likely that your issue is also caused by the latest version of rmarkdown not properly displaying tidyselect's error message that select statements should now include an all_of() or any_of() function.

You can read about the documentation here: https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html